# can I use String literal types for syntactic sugar?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I can use the literal types to give the user some suggestions but without depriving him of using custom strings, i try this :

```
type  fooType = string | 'suggestions-1' | 'suggestions-2';
```

I also tried using the String class and so it seems to work but not good for my purpose

```
type fooType = String | 'suggestions-1' | 'suggestions-2';
```

i reproduce all in this [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAyiATgSwHYHMAqlYF4YDOSa6MAPjAOQECu66URyA9qgQLQCMl5Vt9jECzbsATJQDcMAPTSYAHlz4iKDDHDRgoHPGIYAwgBsAhgQIx8CVaQrU6DJqw7dedgY5HipMuYst7SAGMTMy1taBgAUQAPYwBbCEM8GABvYBgMmAhjVChDI1MCAC5da2xoCWAAX0rApxAYVGY4e0FhYqjYhKSLVPTM7Nz8kI6AIkCaImY40Z8FJRhMAAtYAEkAEUiYABNmRuYG-gcGt2P2rh5bI7anMUpqyq0NWBj4xKhRXrTMrJy8grMJSsJABBEqNWAdTYDQA7sgQEsWu4hE4Sq9uh8vv0MoN-iMSuNJiBpjAAEY0Q6tIizWTzfDLNabQhUk7XDzOS58FnncRkikwYyGAh7OEIgUwABmiCgsECS2YyECUAeYTQICgiAlxiVMFWqHVmu1UAAYohpgAZZCkxDGRBgPo-XHDQolFQkapaWkI2WsCXIUhoGBQaIG1CCnbIQXMUjSgjQQINb26-UarVK00Wq02u0wIqQ+rqFYABTNpKScRKeoNaZNZriluttvt+FFiO5TiknrkUL9AdQQZDGrDhgjUZjjHjiZWyerRoz9azTbzUKIAsrKcN6brDezzf2SLOTiAA)

Comment: Please provide more context for your IDE screenshots. How is the `panelClass` property(?) you're trying to initialize defined? [Here's an example of the kind of context I mean on the TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAKuaBeKBnYAnAlgOwHMoAfKAcgwFdDCItc58MBaARnNIutvuEeYsATOQDcAKHGhIUAKIAPAIYBbMABs0UAN7ioeqGEX4IagMJrFGDAC5YCZJAkBfCeIDGTLFAi2FK9Zo6+gZGJuaWNlAARFFQAPRxUAA8qOgA6kbAmDR0DJ5QAEZUWYpqGHBQAO64wAAWUIpQAGbYENButXC4bhDiLkA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
type StringAndOthers<T> = T | (string & Record<never, never>);
type FooType = StringAndOthers<"suggestions-1" | "suggestions-2">;

const suggestion: FooType = 'suggestions-1';
const suggestion1: FooType = 'suggestions-2';
const suggestion3: FooType = 'suggestions-4';
```

Answer (score -2):

I think a better approach would be to declare an enum first

```
export enum abc {
    a = 'A',
    b = 'B'
   }
```

and then declare your type:

```
a:abc|string
```

and while assigning maybe use values from abc instead of typing strings